# How do I install tun/tap on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04

I'm trying to run vpnc I get this error

```
vpnc-connect: can't open /dev/net/tun, check that it is either device char 10 200 or (with DevFS) a symlink to ../misc/net/tun (not misc/net/tun): No such device
vpnc-connect: can't initialise tunnel interface: No such device
```

However when I check for the tun device I get

```
root@t............:~# ls -l /dev/net/tun 
crw------- 1 root root 10, 200 2012-11-02 01:49 /dev/net/tun
```

This is Ubuntu 10.04 32bit running on a VPS with tun/tap enabled. I had to ask the administrator to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running vpnc-connect as root? The ls output shows the device is only readable and writeable by the root user.

Comment: Yes I'm running it as root

Comment: Yes I'm running it as root